# Creating a chat room - got an error [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python

I created a server/client code to create a chat room using socket programming and multi-threading.I encountered an error that i dont seem to understand The server  code is working, but i am facing issues with the client code and idk why it is saying its not a socket. i would appreciate any help on this.

**Server code**

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# checks whether sufficient arguments have been provided
# if len(sys.argv) != 3:
#     print ("missing arguments enter: <IP address> <port number>")
#     exit()

# first argument from command prompt is IP address
IP_address = '127.0.0.1'
# second argument from command prompt is port number
Port = 12000
# binds the server to an entered IP address and specified port number.
server.bind((IP_address, Port))

# listens for 10 active connections
server.listen(10)
list_of_clients = []

def clientthread(conn, addr):
    # sends a message to the client whose user object is conn
    conn.send("Welcome to Network Programming chatroom!")
    # broadcast to other that a new client has joined 
    message_to_send = "<" + addr[0] +", " + str(addr[1]) + "> joined"
    broadcast(message_to_send, conn)
    while True:
        try:
            message = conn.recv(4096)
            if message:
                # prints the message and address of the user who just sent the message
                print ("<" + addr[0] + ", " + str(addr[1]) + ">: " + message)
                # call broadcast function to send message to all other clients
                message_to_send = "<" + addr[0] +", " + str(addr[1]) + ">: " + message
                broadcast(message_to_send, conn)
            else:
                ''' message have no content if the connection is broken, then 
                send message to others and remove the connection'''
                print("connection : <" + addr[0] + ", " + str(addr[1]) + "> disconnected")
                message_to_send = "<" + addr[0] +", " + str(addr[1]) + "> left"
                broadcast(message_to_send, conn)
                remove(conn)
                break
        except:
            print("error occurred and ignored with: <" + addr[0] +", " + str(addr[1]) + "> connection")
            continue

""" broadcast function is used to broadcast a message to all
clients (but not the sender) """
def broadcast(message, connection):
    for client in list_of_clients:
        if client != connection:
            try:
                client.send(message)
            except:
                client.close()
                # if the link is broken, remove the client
                remove(client)

''' remove function to remove the object from the list of clients '''
def remove(connection):
    if connection in list_of_clients:
        list_of_clients.remove(connection)

print("Welcome to Network Programming chatroom!\nServer is waiting for clients...")
while True:

    """ accepts a connection request and stores two parameters:  
    conn socket object and addr of the connected client"""
    conn, addr = server.accept()

    """ maintains a list to keep track of all available clients in the chatroom"""
    list_of_clients.append(conn)

    # prints the address of the user that just connected
    print (addr[0], addr[1], " joined")
    # creates an individual thread for every client 
    start_new_thread(clientthread,(conn,addr))
conn.close()
server.close()
```

**Client code**

```
import socket
import select
import sys
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# if len(sys.argv) != 3:
#     print ("missing arguments enter: <IP address> <port number>")
#     exit()
IP_address = '127.0.0.1'
Port = 12000
server.connect((IP_address, Port))
while True:
    # create a list to maintain possible input streams
    sockets_list = [sys.stdin, server]
    """ Two possible inputs scenarios. Either the
    user enters text to send to other clients, or the 
    server is sending a message to the client. """

    """ select system call returns from sockets_list, the stream 
    that is reader for input. So for example, if the server sent a message, then the if condition will hold true below. 
    If the user wants to send a message, the else
    condition will evaluate as true"""
    print("wait on select call...")
    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(sockets_list,[],[])
    print("select call returned")
    print("read_sockets: ", read_sockets)
    #print("write_sockets: ", write_sockets)
    #print("error_sockets: ", error_sockets)
    for socks in read_sockets:
        if socks == server:
            message = socks.recv(4096)
            if(len(message) != 0):
                print(message)
            # server sent empty message, print error and leave
            else:
                print("Server is down, join later once it is up!")
                exit()
        else:
            message = sys.stdin.readline()
            server.send(message)
            sys.stdout.write("<You>")
            sys.stdout.write(message)
            sys.stdout.flush()

server.close()
```

**Output on client**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/a/Desktop/Network Programming 2/chat-client.py", line 23, in <module>
    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(sockets_list,[],[])
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
wait on select call...
```

Answer (score 1):

You put `sys.stdin` on your `sockets_list`. It is, as the error says, not a socket. On Unix that would be okay, but on Windows you can't do it.

Comment: @THEMISSINGLINK I don't know. Probably some Win32-specific function that may or may not be available from Python. I don't spend much time on Windows, sorry.